# Removing non-alphanumerics but maintain latin characters

Tags: java, regex

From an input string I would like to get rid of the non-alphanumeric characters (`:`, `-`, etc.) but maintain latin characters. Also replace the blank spaces `" "` with `"-"`.

This is my try, but I dont know how to maintain the latin characters.

```
String title ="NEYÑO: HOW ARE YÓU MATE";
title = title.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "").replace(" ", "-").toLowerCase();
System.out.println(title);
```

Output:

```
neyo-how-are-yu-mate
```

Desired output:

```
neyño-how-are-yóu-mate
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  `[^\p{Alnum}\s]+` with the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` option to keep all Unicode letters and digts:

```
String title ="NEYÑO: HOW ARE YÓU MATE";
title = title.replaceAll("(?U)[^\\p{Alnum}\\s]+", "").replace(" ", "-").toLowerCase();
System.out.println(title); // => neyño-how-are-yóu-mate
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/RIYZPP)

**Details**:

- `(?U)` - n embedded variant of the [`Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS)
- `[^...]` - a [negated character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) matching any single char that does not belong to:

  - [`\p{Alnum}`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) - any alphanumeric character
  - [`\s`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum) - any whitespace character
- `+` - a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) matching 1 or more occurrences.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`\p{IsLatin}` character property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) to detect latin character in Java:

```
String title ="NEYÑO: HOW ARE YÓU MATE";
title = title.replaceAll("(?!\\p{IsLatin})[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "").replace(" ", "-").toLowerCase();
System.out.println(title);

//=> neyño-how-are-yóu-mate
```

`(?!\\p{IsLatin})[^A-Za-z0-9 ]` will match any non-alphanumeric or space character that is not a latin character.